# what kind of open source license for a project which uses other open sources files

Tags: c#, open-source, licensing

I am writing a C# WPF project and I have a question about what license I should assign to my project.
I am using other open source codes for internal processing such as mathematical calculation or displaying data in a good-looking plot.

Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License, Microsoft sdk end user restrictions and The Code Project Open License (CPOL) are some of the license or agreement of the codes I am using from third party.

They provide full access to their codes so  I can easily copy and paste those functions in a new class file? Do I need to give credit to them in my own work, even when it will be for an open source project?

Comment: "Do I need to give credit" For CC & CPOL, yes, using it for an open source project doesn't magically remove the requirement. For Microsot SDK you need to be more specific. In general, even one of the loosest license like MIT License (which allow it to be included on closed source software) still insist on giving credit.

Comment: @Martheen  There is no formal definition of "Open Source". Some definitions in fact do magically remove the requirement for citation.

Comment: Actually, I will be glad to give credit to those people who did something and in some way, help me to safe time so I can done my work but I am worry about what kind of license my project should use

Comment: @Martheen Microsoft SDK prohibit use of code for commercial use so I guess that take the code and use it in an open source should be OK for a mega big company such as Microsoft

Comment: @nicomp : I said "using it for open source project". Whatever usage I use for a code originated in CC or CPOL license can't remove the requirement.

Comment: @PabloGonzalez : No it isn't. Open source is not non commercial.

Comment: Hi there! Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow since it is not a direct, programming related issue, but rather about licensing. You may be able to get an answer at [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com). Be sure to read their on-topic page too. :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. [[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)] for details and the [[help]] for more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that the dependencies in most cases do not affect the license you use for your project. For example, if you leave project links to MIT, Apache, even LGPL libraries, you can use whatever licenses you like. GPL is a typical exception.

So learn the details of each licenses of your dependencies and refer to their FAQs for further reference.

If you do not link to the libraries, but use their source files directly and even modify them, then it might trigger many more restrictions based on each licenses covering them. For instance LGPL will require your project to be released under LGPL.

Sometimes, your choice might even lead to an invalid/incompatible result. Then you will have to drop some dependencies and resort to other alternatives.

Microsoft SDKs are special. I think many of them allow you to compile against, but some libraries from the SDKs might not be redistributed with your project binaries or source code. So you need to carefully review which SDKs are in use and what are the restrictions of each.

Last advice, find a lawyer.